# Migrate cPickled objects to a new class with the same __getstate__ format

Tags: python, pickle

I'm using cPickle to serialize and deserialize instances of a class. I've recently moved a few classes into different packages and now I'm noticing that cPickle/pickle stores the class name and the package it comes from.

```
>>> class A(object):
    pass

>>> dumps(A())
'ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np1\n(c__main__\nA\np2\nc__builtin__\nobject\np3\nNtRp4\n.'
```

Notice how `__main__` is stored because I ran that code in the main python interpreter.

If I try to unpickle the many objects I have stored this way, I'll get an `ImportError` complaining that since I moved the classes around, the old class doesn't exist in the location where it is expected.

I haven't changed the format of `__getstate__` or `__setstate__`. I've only changed the location of the class that needs to be deserialized. Is there a way to migrate these objects so that I don't run into problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate your data, you must provide a reference to the new object at the old location, and dump the data again:

```
old_location.A = new_location.A
data = loads(pickle_data)
pickle_data = dumps(data)
```

and now, `pickle_data` contains a reference to `new_location.A`.

Comment: While this works (I think), it would be useful to have a solution that didn't require unpickling the pickle.

Comment: Is there a way I could get just the data that would have been passed to `__setstate__`? So rather than cPicle deserialising the data the whole way it would only go to that step.

Comment: If you want the read and write the pickle protocol, read the documentation.